# Pandas foward fill in between - same values

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to do the following:

Supposing I have the following column on pandas, where there will be always two values that are equal in sequence.

```
l = [np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 5, np.nan,  2, np.nan, 2, 1, 1]
```

How can I fill NaN values only in between the interval of similar values ?

expected output:

```
[np.nan, np.nan, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, np.nan, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, np.nan,  2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

I could only find this answer, which is not the same problem:

[Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61292759/how-to-fill-elements-between-intervals-of-a-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Solution with `ffill` and `bfill`

```
f = df['col'].ffill()
b = df['col'].bfill()

df['col'].mask(f == b, f)
```

---

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2     10.0
3     10.0
4     10.0
5     10.0
6     10.0
7      NaN
8      4.0
9      4.0
10     4.0
11     5.0
12     5.0
13     5.0
14     NaN
15     2.0
16     2.0
17     2.0
18     1.0
19     1.0
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
m = df['l'].eq(df['l']).cumsum()
out = df.groupby(m).apply(lambda g: g.fillna({'l': g['l'].max()}) if g.name % 2 else g)
```

Detailed explaination:

Assume you have the dataframe

```py
l = [np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 5, np.nan,  2, np.nan, 2, 1, 1, np.nan]

df = pd.DataFrame({'l': l})
```

```
print(df)

       l
0    NaN
1    NaN
2   10.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6   10.0
7    NaN
8    4.0
9    NaN
10   4.0
11   5.0
12   NaN
13   5.0
14   NaN
15   2.0
16   NaN
17   2.0
18   1.0
19   1.0
20   NaN
```

You can use the feature that NaN is not equal with NaN to create a `cumsum`.

```py
df['m'] = df['l'].eq(df['l']).cumsum()
```

```
print(df)

       l   m
0    NaN   0
1    NaN   0
2   10.0   1
3    NaN   1
4    NaN   1
5    NaN   1
6   10.0   2
7    NaN   2
8    4.0   3
9    NaN   3
10   4.0   4
11   5.0   5
12   NaN   5
13   5.0   6
14   NaN   6
15   2.0   7
16   NaN   7
17   2.0   8
18   1.0   9
19   1.0  10
20   NaN  10
```

We can notice that the `True` only occurs in pairs. The first line could only be `True` or `False`, so no matter what the first line is

- The cumsum to the start `True` of first `True` pair could only be `1`
- The cumsum to the end `True` of first `True` pair could only be `2`

This happens to other `True` pairs: the cumsum to the start `True` is odd number, the cumsum to the end `True` is even number.

With this in mind, we can do a groupby then only fill the odd sum value with the not non value in group.

```py
out = df.groupby(m).apply(lambda g: g.fillna({'l': g['l'].max()}) if g.name % 2 else g)
```

```
print(out)

       l
0    NaN
1    NaN
2   10.0
3   10.0
4   10.0
5   10.0
6   10.0
7    NaN
8    4.0
9    4.0
10   4.0
11   5.0
12   5.0
13   5.0
14   NaN
15   2.0
16   2.0
17   2.0
18   1.0
19   1.0
20   NaN
```

Comment: Nice approach, thanks for the explanation